# Draping UI over underlying Full Text Queries in website

Tags: javascript, postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.2

I am just building a website, and the search part of it implements (on the back-end) a full text search with PostgreSQL.

Problem is: if the user puts spaces between words it generates an error (`42601: syntax error in tsquery`), so you have ampersands between words or other logical operators, you cannot have blank spaces between words.

Is there anything pre-built UI (Javascript) wise to handle this type of formatting or remind the user to put the appropriate logical operator in the search box?